# GNU Octave method to operate on each item in a matrix. octave "arrayfun(...)" example

Tags: linux, function, octave

In GNU Octave version 3.4.3, I am having trouble applying a custom function to operate on each item/element in a matrix.

I have a (2,3) matrix that looks like:

```
mymatrix = [1,2,3;4,5,6];

mymatrix

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
```

I want to use each element of the matrix as an input, and run a custom function against it, and have the output of the function replace the content of mymatrix item by item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler way, As Nasser Pointed out, the following octave code:

```
f=@(x) x+5;
A = [1, 0, -1; 3, 4, 5];
result = f(A)
result
```

applies (x+5) to every element passed in, it prints:

```
result =
    6    5    4
    8    9   10
```

Comment: This example is correct, but works only because you add a scalar to a matrix, which would work even without applying a function, but simply as `A+5`. But it does not necessarily work for more complex functions, which includes taking negative powers of elements etc. See my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26415689/182371) for an example of how to write that for a more complicated scenario.

Answer (score 78):

[arrayfun](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Function-Application.html) works well for this:

```
arrayfun(@(x) 1/(1+e^(-x)), [0, 1; 2, 3])
```

Output:

```
ans =

   0.50000   0.73106
   0.88080   0.95257
```

This basically runs function `1/(1+e^(-x))` on each element of the matrix/vector.

Comment: this is a correct answear to the problem in question. Thanks Nikita

Comment: I found a bit easier implementation ```func = @(x) (1 ./ (1 .+ e.^(-x)));

g = func(z);
```

Comment: @SochiX or if you want to save yourself from having to write anonymous function: `g = (1 ./ (1 .+ e.^(-z)))`

Comment: If using Octave or perhaps another tool like Matlab you don't need to use element-wise notation for addition as addition applies to all elements by default so g = 1 ./ (1 + e.^(-z)) should work

Comment: You gave me the exact answer to the problem I was trying to solve for my course.  I feel like I cheated now lol.

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively you can use the element-wise operators like the following (note the dot prefix):

- .+
- .-
- ./
- e.^

For example

```
mymatrix = 1 ./ (1 .+ e.^(-mymatrix));
```

Comment: Look like the . operators are being deprecated (as per the octave command line: "warning: the '.+' operator was deprecated in version 7 and will not be allowed in a future version of Octave; please use '+' instead"

Answer (score 9):

### **Put this code in filename called "myfun.m"**

```
function [ out ] = myfun(num)
  out = num + 5;
end
```

Put this code in filename called "main.m"

```
arrayfun(@myfun, [1, 0, -1; 3, 4, 5] )
```

Output:

```
ans =
   6   5   4
   8   9   10
```

Notice how the procedure (add 5) was applied to each item in the matrix.

### **PROTIP: Why this code on a sufficiently large matrix won't max out your quad-core CPU.**

Below is an analysis of the `arrayfun`'s capabilities from the perspective of Vectorization down through lowlevel C.  Down straight to multi-core and multi-thread optimization on the bare metal:

This `arrayfun` code is "vectorized", and GNU Octave packages this code to be handed to pre-optimized C code rather than having GNU Octave manage its own glacial iteration.  Operations performed in a vectorized way like this above are between 2 and 5 orders of magnitude faster than if you put this in a for loop.  Vectorized code like this is usually good-enough for typical tasks, but if extracting every rev of horsepower from your Alienware's QUAD-CHIP 32-Core hyperthreaded CPU is mission critical, keep reading.

Don't make the mistake of saying this code is "multi-threaded" or "multi-core" because it's not.  C code is still processing this code in an iterative first-in-first out queue-like way.  The 4th addition must wait for the 3rd, and 3rd must wait for the 2nd.  Your CPU is twiddling its thumbs while this iteration occurs.  If you want your sixteen-core CPU under your desk maxing out its CPU use to 100% while this operation is executing, then there is no escape: you must stop and re-define this problem in a multi-threaded and multi-core oriented way.  Multi-thread and multi-core is beyond the scope of this answer, the easiest way is to define your octave code to spawn 8 separate parallel `job1.m` through `job8.m` files that run all at the same time, have all of them process 1/8th of the task at hand, at the end wait for all to finish then rejoin the answer.  GNU Octave Vectorization here does NOT equal Multi-threaded down on the metal.

Comment: Will the element-wise implementation (`1 ./ (1 - e .^ -A)`) also be vectorized, or do you need to use `arrayfun` to get the vectorization benefits?